# How to set min. width as a restriction for a value of an element in XML?

Tags: xml

I need to know what is the restriction on minimum width of the value for a username?
I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
xmlns="http://www.google.com"
xmlns:xs="http://www.google.com"
xs:schemaLocation="http://www.google.com">
    <xs:users>
        <xs:element1 name="username" type="xs:string">
            <xs:restrictions>
                <xs:minWidth="5"/>
            </xs:restrictions>
        </xs:element1>
    </xs:users>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom `simpleType` derived from `xs:string` which enforces a minimum string length of 5:

```
<xs:simpleType name="UserString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="5" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Then you can use it in your original XSD document:

```
<xs:users>
    <xs:element1 name="username" type="UserString"/>
</xs:users>
```